# Can't find manually added records using the search box?

Tags: jhipster

I'm migrating a webapp using jhipster so I already have a database with a lot of records that have to be in the new application.

Once I created the entity I added the records from my old database using:

```
INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM <old-database>.<table>;
```

When I execute the webapp and search for a record in the entity view it doesn't show any old records (only the ones added using the Add button in the webapp).

I'm using MySQL for dev and prod, and I selected ElasticSearch when I was generating the app. The entity view shows the table with all the old records, but when I search for one using the search box it doesn't find them.

What am I doing wrong? Is that the correct way to insert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using JHipster together with elasticsearch assumes, your app is fully aware of managing its search index. While inserting data on your own, your search index becomes inconsistent to your database, what is obvious.

In your case I suggest to install the [JHipster elasticsearch reindexer](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer) module, which enables you to reindex the search index at any time you want. After reindexing, your old data should also appear in your JHipster application